# What's the point of C# Method Parameters?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I'm new to coding, and I'm curious as to why Method Parameters are useful. What's the point to them when I can create a variable within the method which should execute when I call on it? What's the point of giving it that parameter?

[image]

Comment: It lets you say hi to different people without having to write a new method each time.

Comment: Try to say hi to 10.000.000 people ;-)

Comment: Reusability! For example `WriteLine` is a method that takes a parameter and it eventually shows up on your screen. Imagine the method didn't exist, go and try to create such a method.

Comment: In your case it's simple, it just calls `WriteLine` but what if it was doing something very complex and you need to call that complex operation many times, do you want to write the complex operation over and over? No, of course not. Write the complex operation once, make sure it works and then call it as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters can be used for a couple different things. The most practical use is to avoid repetition as Phong said in their answer. For example, if I want to print a single line of red text to the console, I could do this:

```cs
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("This is some red text");
Console.ResetColor();

Console.WriteLine("This is some boring white text");

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("And this is some more red text!");
Console.ResetColor();
```

OR I could create a function with an input parameter for the text to display red like this:

```cs
static void WriteRed(string output){
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ResetColor();
}

WriteRed("This is some red text");
Console.WriteLine("This is some boring white text");
WriteRed("And this is some more red text!");
```

As you can see, we turned this task from a 3 line task, to a 1 line task, which would not be possible without input parameters. This will be very useful in case we need to write in red anywhere else in the program.

Obviously this is a pretty simple example, and in more complex programs this could easily save you 100+ lines.

Another use is for organization. Let's say you have a program that takes user input and processes it in some way. Using functions with input parameters, you can put the user input gathering in one .cs file, and the processing in another.

Parameters are also really useful in constructors, which if you haven't gotten to yet, are just functions that are called when a new instance of an object is created.

Comment: Okay, so practically methods are a way of cleaning and reducing lines of code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, let's say you wanted to say hello to more than just Mike. 
You could do this:

```
SayHi("Mike");
SayHi("Amy");
SayHi("Sam");
```

Let's take it a step further. You can create a collection of names, and say hi to any number of people

```
List<string> people = new List<string> { "Mike", "Amy", "Sam", "John", "Mindy" };
foreach (string person in people) 
{
    SayHi(person);
}
```

As you can see, the `SayHi()` function is reuseable because you can call it any number of times.

And for one more step further, let's say that later you realized that you didn't want to say `"Hello " + name`, you wanted to say, `"Hello, " + name + ". How are you?"`
then you'd only have to change the code in one place and all the times it was used will be affected.

Adding a parameter is a way to say "This piece of reusable code is only useful as long as it has this value to use". In your sample code, the value that `SayHi` needs is a name because it needs to know whom to say hi to.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't fully learn what you said in your other bit of code, but I get the gist of things haha. Now I'm thinking, it sounds similar to how you would use an array. Am I completely off here, or are they similar? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CodingMike Correct. In .NET, any type of data structure that is made to hold a group of similar items can be referred to as a collection. Arrays great examples of that, and so are Lists (and there are others). The `foreach` is a built-in way to *iterate*, or loop through a collection. It basically takes you through that collection, 1 by 1, in order, and lets you do something with that item. In my code, I am looping through each name. Each time, inside the loop, the variable `person` is going to represent the the current name I'm working with.

Comment: Hmmm okay. Is there a reason you would use an array over a method or a method over an array then?

Comment: @CodingMike You are talking about 2 different concepts. An array is type of thing that lets you store data. A method is a thing that let's you do things with data. If you pretend that my code above was an array instead of a List `string[] names = new string[] { "Mike", "Amy" };`. That array is storing names. In your code sample, `static void SayHi(string name)` is a method that let's you do something with a name.

Comment: Aaah okay I think I understand now. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

> What's the point of giving it that parameter?

It helps you `Reuse` some actions with the same steps. [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

As you can see, You just pass the param then inside the method will help you dosomething ("Hello" + passedparameter)

Comment: So you're saying it's useful because I don't have to reuse the same code multiple times? Sorry for being such a newby but why would you want to reuse code multiple times? Thanks. :)

Comment: Just remember [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). It means you should wrapper all actions with the same behavior into a method. As a result, you can get the output with the same format without any duplicate actions.

Comment: @CodingMike Because if later you want to say "Hi" instead of "Hello", you're gonna change it once instead of multiple places and risk doing mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You should read the fundamentals of OOP (object oriented programming). This will help you understand basic principles like method overloading, overriding and inheritance which are commonly used. Instead of writing multiple single-line statements you can create functions that are structured, cleanly written code. Also, following different design patterns, it allows us to give functions the ability to handle single responsibilities and make everything cleaner imo!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming

Comment: Alright I'll take a look at this, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

> C# is Object-oriented programming language

Object-oriented programming, or OOP, is an approach to problem-solving where all computations are carried out using objects. An object is a component of a program that knows how to perform certain actions and how to interact with other elements of the program.
Once you have created objects, you want them to be able to do something. This is where methods come in. A method in object-oriented programming is a procedure associated with a class. A method defines the behavior of the objects that are created from the class. Another way to say this is that a method is an action that an object is able to perform. The association between method and class is **called binding**.

> Consider the example of an object of the type '**person**,' created using
>   the person class. **Method**s associated with this class could consist of
>   things like **walking and driving**. Methods are sometimes confused with
>   functions, but they are distinct. A function is a combination of
>   instructions that are combined to achieve some result. A function
>   typically requires some input (called arguments/**parameters**) and
>   **returns some results**. For example, consider the example of driving a
>   car. To determine the mileage, you need to perform a calculation using
>   the distance driven and the amount of fuel used. You could write a
>   function to do this calculation. The arguments going into the function
>   would be **distance and fuel consumption**, and the result would be
>   mileage. **Anytime you want to determine the mileage**, you simply **call
>   the function** to perform the calculation.

How does this differ from a method? A function is independent and not associated with a class. You can use this function anywhere in your code, and you don't need to have an object to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`What's the point to them when I can create a variable within the method which should execute when I call on it`

If you create a variable inside the method you can only assign it with one value at the time of code writing, but if you pass it as a parameter you can dynamically assign whatever value you want when you call the method later, even a value you don't know at the time of code writing, this value can be assigned on the run time.

Also, methods are used to encapsulate some logic, let say you want a method to calculate the area of a circle which is `π r2`, you know the value of the PI `π` because it is a constant which is almost 3.14, but you don't know the radius value `r` because it varies from circle to another so you need to pass it to the method as parameter.